# What is this "spatula fork" utensil's actual name?

Tags: equipment, utensils

We used to have this exact fork-like spatula but it recently broke. We are looking to buy a replacement but we don't know what it's called so it is difficult to look up to even know where to buy it.

It's like a cross between a fork and a flat head spatula, slightly arched, and tapered at the tip. Non-stick pan safe.

[image: screenshots of utensil]

[image: picture 2]

Comment: Did the stock photo you just copied, above, have a caption giving a name?

Comment: it just said "Food serving kitchen spatula fork" and that's no use really when we're trying to buy this particular tool

Comment: Yah, I've never seen anything just like it.  There's a number of pasta forks, serving forks, and fork-whisks that are *similar*, but not quite the same design.

Answer (score 5):

This is a modern day version of a Foley Fork. Authentic ones are very rare and collectible. My Aunt swore she could not make her (Best in the world) yeast rolls without her Foley Fork for the dough.

Answer (score 1):

The closest things that I could find were called 'whisking forks'  (which I like the idea of ... I use a fork to whisk as I hate cleaning balloon whisks)

- https://smile.amazon.com/Kuhn-Rikon-Silicone-Whisking-Flexible/dp/B06Y1B4Y82
- [https://www.amazon.com/Kuhn-Rikon-Silicone-Wrapped-Whisking/dp/B07JYDFCP9](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07JYDFCP9)

Not all are good as a spatula, though.  This one has balls on the end so it's more like a flat whisk:

- https://smile.amazon.com/Calphalon-Nylon-Whisking-Omelette-Turner/dp/B00JTUG6ZK

Comment: I once saw an ad for https://whiskwiper.com/. Never tried it myself, but if you hate the cleaning so much, maybe it is the thing for you?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a spatula that could double as a spaghetti fork. I don't see the particular utility of this design, but I can imagine stir-frying and removing something like pad-thai with this utensil.

I think the image title in your comment, "food serving... spatula/fork" is pretty accurate.

Answer (score 0):

This exact fork is available from IKEA under the name GNARP in a 5 piece set. I have it however it's already peeling after eight months of light use so I don't recommend it if you're looking for longevity.

Comment: It appears that the GNARP set on IKEA's site right now (US) has 3 pieces, and none of them is this fork/spatula.

Comment: Same on IKEA UK site - a three piece set, one of which IKEA labels a 'turner', and is *sort of like* the pictured item but not actually the same